# encrypting a python dictionary using client_id for using it as a token

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have client_id something like this  'xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'

I have a python dict like this

```
{
   "name" : "M.S.Dhoni",
   "job" : "Wicket keeper"
}
```

Is there any way encrypt this dictionary based on the client_id to make it use as a token for each and every server call.

plz give me hint how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Try to find more about `jwt.decode(dct,JWT_SECRET, algorithm='HS256')` it will encrypt your dict .

Comment: Yeah, Thank you.. :)